# Resources on website summarization using LLMs

Tags: nlp, llm, automatic-summarization

I am working on a problem where I have to summarize business websites. I have to generate a short 100 word summary of the primary function of a given website.

I am familiar with langchain url summarization and langchain document summrization. Using these tools can someone suggest some high level ideas regarding website summarization design or point to some resources regarding the same.

Any other related ideas are also welcome.